# How to find the widget's current size to set the minimum size for the constraints in the Flutter?

Tags: flutter, constraints, constrainedbox, boxconstraints

I want to know how can I find a widget's default size to set it as `constraints: minHeight` or  `constraints: maxHeight` properties?

For example if I have this widget:

```
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // right menu 1
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight - 16,
                    minHeight: 100,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: Colors.blue[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // right menu 2
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight - 16,
                    minHeight: 100,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: Colors.red[200],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

And I want to set `minHeight` to the container's default height instead of hardcoded 100.

Comment: (If I am not wrong)More like widget adapt the minimum size, some are needed to config, which widget you like to provide constrains, and also it is depended on parent widget. It will easy if you could provide exact widget, your snippet. Also, you can use key to get widget size

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: I tried to add an example.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? what's your goal?

Comment: @pskink: My goal is locking a widget to get smaller than it's default size when the running app window size changes.

Answer (score 0):

> There's a Widget for that

Have you tried [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)?